# How to let git config file recognize aliases that defined in ~/.bashrc?

Tags: git, bash, alias, git-config

I put some aliases for launch text editor, so I don't have to type in the full path. However, when I try to use these aliases in git config file. It seems like can't recognize those aliases. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Care to provide a relevant snippet from your Git config? Anyway, one reason for this might be that you put your aliases in an RC-file thich is only read by a login shell and hence the shell started in a non-interactive way (by Git) just does not read that file.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (without bothering to look) that git spawns external commands with something like `execv()` or `/bin/sh/ -c "..."`, so you won't get your environment/functions/aliases. If you need that, you need to create an executable shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
do stuff with your aliases here
```